# How to use custom error handler service across different modules in angular2

Tags: angular

I have created  a module for error logging and i have extended default angular ErrorHandler class
Below is the code

```js
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
private errorLogService: ErrorLogService;

constructor(
    errorLogService: ErrorLogService) {
    this.errorLogService = errorLogService;
}

public handleError( error: any ) : void {

    // Log to the console.
    try {
        console.error( error.message );
        console.error( error.stack );
    } catch ( handlingError ) {         
        console.error( handlingError );
    }

   }
```

I have bootstrapped this in my exceptionhandling module. I want to use this in my other modules - adminmodule and clientmodule. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Angular to use your "GlobalErrorHandler" adding the provider into your **app.module** (because it represents the root level of your application)

This is an example of app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { GlobalErrorHandler } from './error-handler'; //<-- adapt the "from" to your file
import { ServicesModule } from './services';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler, 
      useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```